# Is this a hyperbolic PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

> > Is the PDE
> >     $$
> > (1+x^2)^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+2x(1+x^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0\text{ in }\Omega:=\mathbb{R}^2
> > $$
> >     hyperbolic?

To answer this I set

$a(x,y):=(1+x^2)^2, b(x,y):=0, c(x,y)=-1$, then $b^2-ac=(1+x^2)^2 >0$

and this we had as a criterion for hyperbolicism.

Am I right?

Comment: You might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Classification) interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right but $\Delta(x, y)=b^2-4ac$. If we have a second-order PDE 
$$a(x, y)u_{xx}+b(x ,y)u_{xy}+c(x, y)u_{yy}+ F(x, y, u, u_x, u_y)=0$$ (called semilinear equation), then we can classify the eqn. according to the sign of $\Delta(x, y).$ It is hperbolic on $\Omega$ if $\Delta(x, y)>0$ , parabolic on $\Omega$ if $\Delta(x, y)=0$ and elliptic on $\Omega$ if $\Delta(x, y)<0$ for all $(x, y)\in\Omega$ .

Comment: Hm, we defined hyperbolic as $b^2-ac>0$...

Comment: Probably your equation (instead $b$, should be $2b$) is of the form $a(x, y)u_{xx}+2b(x ,y)u_{xy}+c(x, y)u_{yy}+ F(x, y, u, u_x, u_y)=0$. That' why your $\Delta$ is so.